# Scala 2.11 reflection and annotations (Java) with parameters

Tags: scala, reflection, annotations

I have a simple class-level annotation written in Java:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Collection {
    String name();
}
```

used like:

```
@Collection(name="mytable")
case class Foo(...)
```

I need to introspect classes in Scala 2.11 to obtain the value of the name parameter.  How can I get this info?  I'm up to here:

```
val sym = currentMirror.classSymbol(Class.forName(fullName))
val anno = sym.annotations.head
val annoType = anno.tree.tpe  // I can get this...works
println(anno.tree.children.tail)  // prints List(name = "mytable")
```

I'm close!  I can see my name parameter and its value but this doesn't seem to be accessible like a Map or anything friendly.  How can I get the value of my annotation's parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tree api implements product to get elements out, so this is kind of a hacky demonstration, but you can get out your element:

```
  println(anno.tree.children.last.productElement(1))  // prints "mytable"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can handle using Jackson, then I'd re-use its annotation processing functionality instead of using scala reflection.

```
object Test {
  @Collection(name="mytable")
  case class Foo(bar: String)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val introspector = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector
    val ac = AnnotatedClass.construct(classOf[Foo], introspector, null)
    val annotation = ac.getAnnotations.get(classOf[Collection])

    println(annotation.name())
  }
}
```

If the class does not have the annotation then `annotation` is null.