# How to get the annotations of a method in Scala 2.11

Tags: scala, reflection, annotations, scala-2.11

Let's assume a controller object like this:

```
object Users extends Controller {

  ...

  @ApiOperation(
    httpMethod = "POST",
    nickname = "authenticate",
    value = "Authenticates an user",
    notes = "Returns the JSON Web Token to be used in any subsequent request",
    response = classOf[models.auth.api.Jwt])
  def authenticate = SecuredAction[Users.type]("authenticate").async(parse.json) { implicit request =>
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

How do I get the annotation values of the `authenticate` method at runtime? I've tried this:

```
def methodAnnotations[T: TypeTag]: Map[String, Map[String, Map[String, JavaArgument]]] = {
  typeTag[T].tpe.declarations.collect { case m: MethodSymbol => m }.map { m =>
    val methodName = m.name.toString
    val annotations =  m.annotations.map { a =>
      val annotationName = a.tpe.typeSymbol.name.toString
      val annotationArgs = a.javaArgs.map {
        case (name, value) => name.toString -> value
      }
      annotationName -> annotationArgs
    }.toMap
    methodName -> annotations
  }.toMap
}
```

`methodAnnotations` returns the specified annotation for the specified method and is invoke like this:

```
val mAnnotations = methodAnnotations[T]
val nickname = mAnnotations("myMethodName")("MyAnnotationName")("myAnnotationMemberName").asInstanceOf[LiteralArgument].value.value.asInstanceOf[String]
```

The problem is that when I compile the code above I always get the following warnings:

```
type JavaArgument in trait Annotations is deprecated: Use `Annotation.tree` to inspect annotation arguments
method tpe in trait AnnotationApi is deprecated: Use `tree.tpe` instead
```

What's the correct way to get method annotations with scala 2.11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the solution suggested by [Nate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1028765/nate) is the most clean and efficient... but in my case it would require too much refactoring, so I've just decided to still use Scala reflection. Here is my solution:

```
package utils.common

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

/**
  * Provides functionality for obtaining reflective information about
  * classes and objects.
  */
object ReflectHelper {

  /**
    * Returns a `Map` from annotation names to annotation data for
    * the specified type.
    *
    * @tparam T The type to get class annotations for.
    * @return The class annotations for `T`.
    */
  def classAnnotations[T: TypeTag]: Map[String, Map[String, Any]] = {
    typeOf[T].typeSymbol.asClass.annotations.map { a =>
      a.tree.tpe.typeSymbol.name.toString -> a.tree.children.withFilter {
        _.productPrefix eq "AssignOrNamedArg"
      }.map { tree =>
        tree.productElement(0).toString -> tree.productElement(1)
      }.toMap
    }.toMap
  }

  /**
    * Returns a `Map` from method names to a `Map` from annotation names to
    * annotation data for the specified type.
    *
    * @tparam T The type to get method annotations for.
    * @return The method annotations for `T`.
    */
  def methodAnnotations[T: TypeTag]: Map[String, Map[String, Map[String, Any]]] = {
    typeOf[T].decls.collect { case m: MethodSymbol => m }.withFilter {
      _.annotations.length > 0
    }.map { m =>
      m.name.toString -> m.annotations.map { a =>
        a.tree.tpe.typeSymbol.name.toString -> a.tree.children.withFilter {
         _.productPrefix eq "AssignOrNamedArg"
        }.map { tree =>
          tree.productElement(0).toString -> tree.productElement(1)
        }.toMap
      }.toMap
    }.toMap
  }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you can handle using Jackson, then I'd re-use its annotation processing functionality instead of using scala reflection.

```
object Test {
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.{AnnotatedClass, JacksonAnnotationIntrospector}

  @ApiOperation(
    httpMethod = "POST",
    nickname = "authenticate",
    value = "Authenticates an user",
    notes = "Returns the JSON Web Token to be used in any subsequent request",
    response = classOf[models.auth.api.Jwt])
  def hasAnnotation() {}

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

    val introspector = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector
    val ac = AnnotatedClass.construct(Test.getClass, introspector, null)
    for (method <- ac.memberMethods()) {
      val annotation = method.getAnnotation(classOf[ApiOperation])
      if (annotation != null) {
        println(s"${method.getFullName} -> ${annotation.nickname()}")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll try... but may I ask why Jackson is better than scala reflection? just to be informed ;-)

Comment: @j3d Jackson is widely used, robust, fast, and clean. So... why not if it gets the job done easily =)? Additionally, the Scala reflection API does not give you access to annotation parameters without peeking in (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26635223/scala-2-11-reflection-and-annotations-java-with-parameters/26637228#26637228).

Comment: I've tried... but it doesn't work for me because `SecuredAction` must take a type parameter... and the passed type must be an `object` derived from `Controller`...

Comment: I'm not really sure I see the connection. Your question doesn't use SecuredAction at all except in your method definition (which isn't going to be exposed). Are you not trying to retrieve the annotation on the method "authenticate", or are you trying to get something else?

Comment: `SecuredAction` is a custom action designed to secure controller methods according to the current authorization profile. `SecuredAction` is generic and used by many different controllers. `SecuredAction` automatically reads the method nickname and determines whether or not the current user is authorized to invoke the method (for each nickname there is an entry in the configuration that specifies who can invoke the method associated with that nickname).

Comment: Without a larger code sample I don't think I can help you further; though I'm pretty convinced that you can use jackson to get you what you need. You must be missing some idea/link to make it work. Have you considered TypeTag'ing the generic type on SecuredAction to retrieve the class object? Or considered passing in `this.getClass()` prior to `"authenticate"`?

Comment: Here is the SecuredAction code: http://ideone.com/6dy34l. If I TypeTag the generic type on SecuredAction, it compiles but then it crashes at runtime because it doesn't find the type of the generic (e.g. `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: controllers.auth.Users$`).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know much about how play works; this doesn't make any sense! How is it running your code without the singleton class loaded? FYI, You don't need TypeTag on any methods inside of SecuredAction since it should exist at the class level. An alternative would be to change `apply` to something like `apply[T <: Controller](cls: Class[T], methodName: String)` then invoke like: `SecuredAction(classOf[User.type], "authenticate")...`. At least then it happens at compile time. You may not be able to use reflection yet anyways; are you using the right class loader?