# How to use reflect to get annotation instance in scala 2.11

Tags: scala, reflection

I want get annotation instance by reflect , I have tried to use this method [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26897279/how-to-get-the-annotations-of-a-method-in-scala-2-11) but it doesn't work.

It will be success when annotation field type is basic and without default value,but when the type is complex or has default value , it will be fail.

In my code like:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object ReflectHelper {

  val runtime = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

  /**
   * @param beanClazz target bean class
   * @tparam A target annotation
   * @return  annotation instances
   */
  def getClassAnnotation[A: TypeTag](beanClazz: Class[_]): Option[A] = {
    val typeAnnotation = typeOf[A]
    scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror.classSymbol(beanClazz).toType.typeSymbol.asClass.annotations.find(a => a.tree.tpe == typeAnnotation).map {
      annotation =>
        /*
         *  Has error : scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Select cannot be cast to scala.reflect.api.Constants$ConstantApi
         *  when annotation field use default value
         *
         *  Has error : scala.reflect.internal.Trees$TypeApply cannot be cast to scala.reflect.api.Constants$ConstantApi
         *  when annotation field  type is collection
         */
        val value = annotation.tree.children.tail.map(_.productElement(0).asInstanceOf[Constant].value)
        runtime.reflectClass(typeAnnotation.typeSymbol.asClass).
          reflectConstructor(typeAnnotation.decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod)(value: _*).
          asInstanceOf[A]
    }
  }

}

case class Entity1(idField: String = "id") extends StaticAnnotation

case class Entity2(rels: List[String] = List()) extends StaticAnnotation

@Entity1(idField = "pk")
case class Test1Entity()

@Entity1()
case class Test2Entity()

@Entity2(rels = List("fieldA"))
case class Test3Entity()

class Test extends FunSuite {
  test("Bean Test") {
    //Success
    assert(ReflectHelper.getClassAnnotation[Entity1](classOf[Test1Entity]).get.idField == "pk")
    //Error : scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Select cannot be cast to scala.reflect.api.Constants$ConstantApi
    assert(ReflectHelper.getClassAnnotation[Entity1](classOf[Test2Entity]).get.idField == "id")
    //Error : scala.reflect.internal.Trees$TypeApply cannot be cast to scala.reflect.api.Constants$ConstantApi
    assert(ReflectHelper.getClassAnnotation[Entity2](classOf[Test3Entity]).get.rels(0) == "fieldA")
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind, you can still use Java reflection in Scala to a large extent, and in some cases it's may just be plain simpler.

Comment: This is inherently complex, you have to parse (i.e. traverse and pattern match) the whole syntax tree and check against all possibilities (`Constant`, `ClassSymbol`, methods (for instance `apply` method of `List`) and a lot of other cases). You can refer to the docs of `scala.ref.api` especially `Constants` for more info.